# Get all simple product with REST API

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, rest-api

I want to fetch all the simple product. The result should not include any configurable products.

Currently i am fetching using this http://host/rest/default/V1/products?searchCriteria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Works For me:-**

```
{{www.example.com}}/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=type_id&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=simple
```